# Does light seen from a long glass slab change color initially?

Tags: geometric-optics

Red light has a higher velocity than blue light. So if a body emitting white light is kept at the end of a really long piece of glass (or any substance of higher refractive index for that matter) would an observer at the other end see the light change progressively from red to blue?

Comment: Dispersion depends on the medium, and it is not uniformly true that red will be faster than blue. But, if there is dispersion, can you observe the chirp? Absolutely, given a short enough pulse (which will have a broad spectrum by definition).

Comment: If you speak only about velocity - why do you care? Blue comes picosecods later and from that moment you still see all colors.

Comment: Light travels the same speed through the medium. The reason it may take longer to go through depends on the direction and true length of the path through the glass molecules.

Answer (score 2):

In the infrared this effect is well known. As the comments mentioned, it is called *dispersion* and the resulting time-variable frequency of the signal is called *chirp*. It is one of the main limitations on the bandwidth-distance product achievable in fiber optic communications systems. And it is the reason why long-distance systems require source lasers with very narrow spectra, increasing their cost.

In the visible band, the inherent attenuation due to Rayleigh scattering is much higher than at IR wavelengths, so you would probably not be able to make a long enough fiber (or thick enough piece of glass) to observe substantial chirp, and still have enough light reach the far end to be observed (at least by the human eye).